# VIM: Map a key in order to insert x number of # at the beginning of a line

Tags: vim

I would to like to insert x number of character # at the beginning of a line followed by a space. My goal is to put headers for markdown easily:

Before:
`Title`

After typing 5+F5
`##### Title`

I just managed to insert # with F5 key: `nnoremap <F5> @='I#<C-V><Esc>'<CR>h`

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is probably a better fit for [Vi.se]. Please note that [cross posting is generally frowned upon](//meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info), so you should either (1) post a new question there and delete this one, or (2) flag your question for a [moderator to migrate](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/269535).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this one is a little more clear if you use vimscript instead of the editing commands.  The following mapping works like this:

- If you don't give a count, it inserts "# " at the beginning of the line.
- If you give a count, it inserts count * "#" followed by " " at the beginning of the line.

Mapping:

```
nmap <F5> :<C-u>call setline('.', substitute(getline('.'), '^', repeat('#', v:count1) . ' ', ''))<Enter>
```

In response to your comment below, here is a version that will modify the current line to have exactly `<count>` hashes followed by one space - even if it already has hashes and a space.  If `<count>` is zero, both the hashes and space are removed.

```
nmap <F5> :<C-u>call setline('.', substitute(getline('.'), '\v^(#+ )?', repeat('#', v:count) . repeat(' ', min([1, v:count])), ''))<Enter>
```

And because This is getting really busy for a one line map, here it is with a function instead:

```
function SetMarkdownHeader()
  let current_line = getline('.')
  let hashes = repeat('#', v:count)
  let maybe_space = repeat(' ', min([v:count, 1]))
  let new_line = substitute(current_line, '\v^(#+ )?', hashes . maybe_space, '')

  call setline('.', new_line)
endfunction

nmap <f5> :<C-u>call SetMarkdownHeader()<Enter>
```

Comment: Many thanks Randy, it works fine. As I am a newbie in vimscript can you please give me the same output for the reverse operation, which is just remove some amount of # (by not touching to the blank character)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your parenthetical statement.  It should remove some amount of '#'s but not touch the blank character?  That seems less useful than just deleting them manually since you'd have to delete the blank manually if you removed them all.

Comment: Again thanks for the function :). Yes indeed if I remove all the # char the blank must be removed also.

Comment: I don't understand the regexp you used, what does it match (\v) with your explanation I may understand why by pressing F5 it removes the leading ### in the current line.

Comment: For information on `\v`, look at `:help /magic`.  Basically it just modifies which characters need to be escaped in the regex.  The reason it removes everything when you just press `F5` is because the count is set to 0 by default, thus it sets the headline to "0" hashes.